# Nesting in Fe-based superconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

Many studies about iron-based superconductors mention the nesting of Fermi pockets, such as [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.1413v1.pdf) or [here](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0812/0812.3704.pdf). As far as I understand it it represents some kind of interplay between different Fermi surfaces.

Does anyone have a clear explanation of what nesting is in the context of Fe-based superconductors, or a source giving such explanation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [previous stackexchange post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45626/fermi-surface-nesting-and-cdw-sdw-sc-orders) on nesting. I will try to briefly explain nesting in the context of the [Terashima et al. paper](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0812/0812.3704.pdf). In Fig 3(C) of the paper there is an illustration of the Fermi surface of a material as measured using ARPES. There are two pockets to this Fermi surface, one pocket near $k=0$ (the $\Gamma$ point) and one pocket near $k=(\pi,0)$ (the $M$ point). These two pockets are said to be nested because there is a single $Q$ vector $Q=(\pi,0)$ that connects many states on the Fermi surface. In other words, you can translate the Fermi surface pocket at $\Gamma$ over to $M$ and it would nearly overlap the Fermi surface pocket already at $M$. If the pockets at $\Gamma$ and $M$ were identical then the nesting would be called perfect. As it stands the nesting is imperfect, so-called quasi-nesting. Nesting (an quasi-nesting) leads to enhancements of interactions and ultimately to exotic phases, such as magnetism or superconductivity. A clearer example of a nested Fermi surface can be found [here](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2008/ph373/karakonstantakis1/). In Fig 1 the Fermi surface for a half-filled electron band on a square lattice is shown. Notice that at exactly half-filling ($n=1$ since the band can hold a density $n=2$ electrons, spin-up and spin-down) the Fermi surface is a square. Then the nesting vector $Q=(\pi,\pi)$ connects many points on the Fermi surface. In this case nesting leads to antiferromagnetism.